# Check if HttpResponse has string or null or image in it

Tags: android, httpresponse

I want to send the imgData as null if server does not returned the image.But with this code it is never returning null.I need to check if HttpResponse contain null or image or the error message when I am sending the response from server..If image is present it is send in form of byte array if not present then null and if error occurs then error message is send.

```
public static byte[] getCommentImage(final int commentId) {
    byte[] imgData = null;
    HttpResponse res= null;
    try {
        res = $.get(COMMENT_IMAGE_URL, new Object[] {"comment_id", commentId });
        HttpEntity resEntity = res.getEntity();
        imgData = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resEntity);
        Log.d("getCommentImage API",imgData+" ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return imgData;
   }
```

Comment: do you have control over the server? what do you mean if HttpResponse contains null?

Comment: If image is not present in db I'm sending data as null

Comment: if you have control over the server, you can arbitrary decide that the first byte of the body of the response is the type, so maybe 0x00 for null, 0xaa for error and 0xff for image, then read the others bytes according to the type

Comment: @lelloman             res = org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42ec7440
This is the value of res when image is present in the DB ..........                  and when image is not present I'm giving echo null from my PHP api and in that case the value of res is org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@424d9a50..

Comment: Why not send a 403 if the server doesn't have the image? like every other HTTP server on the planet?

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP response usually contains a header declaring the content type. 
A "String" (or an HTML page) is usually the content type "text/html", for an image "image/jpeg" or "image/png".

```
resEntity.getContentType().getValue();
```

Furthermore you have the status / result code:

```
res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I assume that the result code is != 200 (HTTP_OK) in case you get a null value.

Comment: I checked in both the cases resEntity.getContentType().getValue() is text/html  When server is sending image and when server is not sending image